# My answer is coming out wrong in this series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac 1{1-n^2}+\frac 2{1-n^2}+\frac 3{1-n^2}+\cdots+\frac n{1-n^2} \right)$$

My answer is coming out to be $-\frac 12$.

I factored out the common $\frac 1{1-n²}$, summed up the numerators to $\frac{n(n+1)}2$, cancelled common factors and divided the numerator and denominator by $n$.

Comment: This seems loaded with misprints. One sums probably k/(k-n^2) from k=1 to k=n (note the k in the denominator), no? Not that the final limit is very different...

Comment: I added $\LaTeX$ to your question. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I checked your work, both in algebra and numerically, and $-\frac 12$ seems to be the correct answer. What do you think it should be?

Comment: Rory Daulton: Yes, that is what I meant, and actually my book gives the answer 'none of these'. The other options were 0 and 1/2.  And there might have been a midprint in the book or something. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer $-\frac{1}2$ seems to be correct.